# WordPress SVN Commit Failed

Tags: wordpress, svn, plugins

My plugin has been approved in wordpress. But I am having trouble to upload the plugin via SVN. When I am filling out the username and passowrd and ticking on the save authentication this box is showing again and comes 4 times. Finally it shows Commit Failed! Please anyone help me how I can solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your credentials aren't accepted, either you're entering them wrong (make sure you've got the correct case, as it's case-sensitive), you don't have the required permissions on the URL you're committing to, or the URL you're committing to is incorrect (again, it's case-sensitive, so make sure that you've got everything perfect).

But to get an authoritative answer, you need to ask the WordPress folks as they're running the server and granted you the access.